# Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE"

Tags: asp.net

I wrote a short code in the notepad and save it as .asp in the inetpub\wwwroot\MyWeb after that when I acccess the address of this page `"http://localhost/MyWeb/test1.asp"` in my chrome this error occurs "Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE" ".I read some pages in this topic but I can't find the solution.

I installed visual studio 2010 before IIS.  should I uninstall visual studio and re install it.

Comment: Are you try to run asp or asp.net ?

Comment: I run Asp.net and I know classic ASP is dead.

Comment: give more description of error and have you added config file

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using II 6.0 and above, so you will need to set IIS to allow activer serverpages for you in the Web Extensions setting

> 1. Start IIS  then go to Web Service Extensions
> 2. A list will appear
> 3. on the right. Select ‘active server pages’ 3) Press the ‘Allow’ button

**Update on comment from OP:**

> By default ASP is not enable on IIS 7 so please use link on how to enable it
>   http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/562/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis/

Comment: I have Windows 7 Ultimate,there is no "Web Service Extension" folder in the IIS Manager.